# Difference between 'image-editor' and 'image-manipulation'?

Tags: discussion, tags

I see Gilles created the tag [image-manipulation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-manipulation), and it happens to be used [exactly once](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4046/remove-extra-tilespace-from-a-montage-imagemagick-composite-image). I'm wondering if that was an oversight, or if it's supposed to be distinct from [image-editor tag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-editor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the `image-manipulation` tag could be applied to **command line tools** such as `convert` or `imagemagick`, whereas `image-editor` would be more relevant to **Image Editing GUI** applications, such as **GIMP**.

So for me these two tags are a bit different.

Comment: The distinction can be a bit vague. I'm now thinking of Nautilus' plugin, which allows one to **resize** or **rotate** images. Following your argument, it seems to me this would fit into [image-manipulation] tag, but then it's GUI.

Comment: @Tshepang: My reasoning was exactly what Stefan explained. For me an editor is interactive, so `montage` or any other automated program doesn't fit `image-editor`. I'm not committed to the tag names, but I do think there should be two different tags.

Comment: @Gilles Curiously, would you tag the Nautilus plugin I mentioned `image-manipulation`?

Comment: @Tshepang: If I want to hand-draw a red circle over a screenshot I'll use an image editor. If I want to trim a large bunch of photos automatically I won't use an image editor. I'm not sure about this Nautilus plug-in as I haven't seen it, it may just be an edge case. Still, it doesn't really sound like an image editor since you'd be manipulating the image as a whole.